# AngularJS: Directive does not have access to controller when element is nested

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

**Question**: Why doesn't my simple directive have access to its controller when the element is used on certain pages?

**Additional Info**: *The directive works* on the main page. The HTML I could not use my directive on is called using `ui-view` and is included below.

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

**Directive**:

```
var postcardAppDirectives = angular.module('postcards.directives', ['postcards.controllers']);

postcardAppDirectives.directive('postcardLink', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        template: '<div class="well">{{ ctrl.ownerObj.user }}</div>',
        controller: 'postcardLinkController as ctrl'
    }
});
```

**Controller**:

```
var PostcardsControllers = angular.module('postcards.controllers', ['postcards.factories', 'postcards.services']);

PostcardsControllers.controller('postcardLinkController', [function ()
    this.ownerObj = {
        "user": 'test_owner',
        "pointofthis": 'inane testing'
    }
}]);
```

**HTML (Does Not Work)**:

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardAccountController as infoCtrl" class="container full-container">

<!------------------ DIRECTIVE REFERENCE HERE -------->        
<postcard-link></postcard-link>

    <h1>
        <small>Welcome</small>
        <username-text></username-text>
    </h1>
    <img ng-show="infoCtrl.user.member_profile.profile_image" ng-src="{{ infoCtrl.user.member_profile.profile_image }}"
         style="min-height:100px;height:100px;" alt='profileImage'/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-md-offset-2" ng-click="infoCtrl.loadPage()">Modify Account</button>
    <div class="row">
...
```

[image: Not working here]

**HTML (Working Fine)**

```
<ng-include src="'static/app/carousel/_carousel.html'"></ng-include>

<postcard-link></postcard-link>
<div class="container">
    <section style="text-align: center">
        <h1>How It Works</h1>
```

[image: Working just fine.]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I still don't understand, though... `ctrl` is the controller alias, correct? In the directive I specify both `postcardLinkController as ctrl` and `{{ ctrl.ownerObj.user }}`. Where should I change the alias?

Comment: syntax error in 'postcardLinkController'. missed curly bracket  after 'function ()'

Comment: Thanks - typo from the copy-paste to SO! The directive works, just not in the place I need it...

Answer (score 0):

I see you used different module that's why one module don't know another module directive. you should use same module.

Like:

js:

```
var app = angular.module('postcards', []);//add dependencies in []

app.directive('postcardLink', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        template: '<div class="well">{{ ctrl.ownerObj.user }}</div>',
        controller: 'postcardLinkController as ctrl'
    }
});

app.controller('postcardLinkController', [function () {
    this.ownerObj = {
        "user": 'test_owner',
        "pointofthis": 'inane testing'
    }
}]);
```

use as usual html:

```
<postcard-link></postcard-link>
```

Comment: Hey - if I'm understanding correctly, you mean the variable at the front of the declaration is different in the controller and directive? Normally you would be right about that. In this case, the modules all come together under a single app, like "angular.module('postcards', ['postcards.controllers', 'postcards...'])" for all relevant submodules.

Comment: yep, module dependencies inject in the same place for a single module otherwise isolate from each another. If project size is small or medium single module is better. Also you can inject custom service or factory dependencies in your controller or directive.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this solves the problem. The issue is not that the directive doesn't work or have access to the controller. The issue is that something is interrupting that access within a certain view.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having the same issue - I don't think it has to do with the module not being imported, because it *is* imported, and I'm having problems with other directives as well.